# Opencv true type font reversing and splitting arabic characters

Tags: python, c++, opencv, arabic, truetype

Arabic letters are written cursively and read from right to left. I'm trying to render the word `مستقبل` which means future and reads from right to left (begins with `م` and ends with `ل`) using opencv's [FreeType2](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d9/dfa/classcv_1_1freetype_1_1FreeType2.html), and a [ttf](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cairo?subset=arabic). Following the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d9/dfa/classcv_1_1freetype_1_1FreeType2.html) example, I do:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/freetype.hpp>


void render_text(const cv::String& text, const cv::String& font){
    int font_height = 60;
    int thickness = -1;
    int line_style = 4;
    int baseline=0;
    cv::Ptr<cv::freetype::FreeType2> ft2;
    ft2 = cv::freetype::createFreeType2();
    ft2->loadFontData(font, 0 );
    cv::Size text_size = ft2->getTextSize(text,
                                     font_height,
                                     thickness,
                                     &baseline);
    cv::Mat img(500, 500, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar::all(0));
    if(thickness > 0){
        baseline += thickness;
    }
    cv::Point origin((img.cols - text_size.width) / 2,
                  (img.rows + text_size.height) / 2);
    ft2->putText(img, text, origin, font_height,
                 cv::Scalar::all(255), thickness, line_style, true );
    cv::imshow("default", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
}


int main() {
    render_text("مستقبل", "Cairo/Cairo-Regular.ttf");
    return 0;
}
```

Which results in (incorrect):

[image: reversed]

I was able to render the word using the same font in the proper order using [PIL](https://python-pillow.org/)

```
import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont


def render_text(text, font, font_size=60):
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font, font_size)
    image = Image.new('RGB', font.getsize(text), (0, 0, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw.text((0, 0), text, (255, 255, 255), font=font)
    cv2.imshow('default', np.array(image))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    render_text('مستقبل', 'Cairo/Cairo-Regular.ttf')
```

which results in (correct):

[image: correct]

But it's slow, which led me to the attempt shown earlier with opencv after failing to find the freetype2 in `opencv-python` or `opencv-contrib-python`. How to get it to render words in the correct order in python or c++? Other opencv alternatives are welcome as long as they:

- Are faster than PIL
- Render in the proper order.
- Don't split letters

Comment: Try pango to render on a cairo surface, then convert that to opencv mat like e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948319/how-to-convert-cairo-image-surface-to-opencv-mat-in-c

Answer (score 0):

That's a [known problem](https://forum.opencv.org/t/emgu-cv-4-5-3-freetype2-class-dont-show-correctly-utf8-text/5649) with the `freetype` module in `opencv_contrib`.

[It has not been reported as an issue yet](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues) (as far as I can see) because freetype text rendering will graduate from being a `contrib` module to being part of OpenCV proper... **in OpenCV 5**.

That being in `contrib` currently is also the reason it's not available to you from the `opencv-python` package. You need the `opencv-contrib-python` package... that might include it.

Hopefully the reimplementation will fix this. I don't know when OpenCV 5 will be released. It is currently under active development.

Comment: It's unavailable in `opencv-contrib-python` and I still get `Error 'module' object has no attribute 'freetype'`. So, any opencv alternatives or workarounds?